# Spring AWS S3: Access to s3 object metadata

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

Is it possible to get object metadata with spring-aws-s3 library? I need access to "ETag" header but as it seems like SimpleStorageResource does not expose way to access objectMetadata and ResourceLoader interface does not expose connection.

What are my options? Just use S3 SDK directly?

Comment: IMHO, access to metadata, and the ability to set metadata is required. For example, it is not possible to write an S3 SimpleStorageResource to a server side encrypted (SSE) bucket because the metadata cannot be set.